# Embedding video using embed tag not working in modern browsers

Tags: html, video, embed, wmv

I have a very simple html page with following content:

```
<embed width="260" height="282" src="rtuner.wmv" showstatusbar="true" showgotobar="true" showdisplay="true" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" type="application/x-mplayer2" name="rTuner" />
```

Note that 'src' attribute of embed element takes a relative url. This very simple html element plays the video in older browsers like Firefox 10, IE8 etc., but it doesn't play in FF 17 and Chrome 27. If 'src' attribute is assigned a absolute URL then the video works again.

Any ideas why so?

EDIT: Observed Firebug console shows this warning - 'Error: Permission denied to access object'. Does this message give any hint?

Comment: You have the answer in your question.. give dynamic fullpath of the video in the "src"

Comment: relative url works in older browsers, it doesn't work in newer versions. The question is why doesn't the video play with embed's relative url in newer versions of browsers while it used to in older versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an WMP plugin issue. If browsers have old wmp plugin `npdsplay.dll`, a new wmp plugin `np-mswmp.dll` has to be installed. http://kb.mozillazine.org/Windows_Media_Player

Answer (score 0):

If you want to embed a video, do it like this..

First, click on the desired video in youtube and click on share

[image]

Next, you click on Embed button

[image]

Now you just **copy the code** that youtube has provided and **paste it in your code**..This will make the video appear in your web page..

Try it..

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>Video examples:</h1>
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/j6gNKR0TMMo"></iframe>

<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/Img/error-lolcat-problemz.jpg">
<embed src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/j6gNKR0TMMo" width="1000" height="600">
<h1>Image examples:</h1>
<h1>Link examples:</h1>
<a href="https://area51.stackexchange.com">Link</a>
```

Comment: While this may be a proper solution, some context/explanation would greatly improve the quality of this post.